# LabVIEW Degrees Converter Program

Tags: labview, converters, degrees

I haven't done any single thing in LabVIEW, but I have one task.
I have to create VI that converts a given angle in degrees (and fractions of degrees) to full turns, degrees, arc minutes, and arc seconds. (f.e. 362.5 degrees = 1 full turn, 2 degrees, 30 minutes, 0 arc second)
Please help me, what would I use to create something like that. Any tips will be just fine.

Comment: This task seems like a great task to get to know the basics of LabVIEW. Just start with an input and an output of your choice and try. In case you really get stuck you can still ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is some quick implementation:

[image: Implementation]